# Was the questions quality, actually, decreased with a new Wizard or not?

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, blog

In the [last blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers), Sara mentioned:

> We also looked at question quality because we wanted to make sure we were helping all people write questions that were likely to get answered. We saw **no decrease in question quality**.

But in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/):

> During Step 1 (the major UI changes plus modals for new question askers), we saw a **1.5% decrease in good quality questions**

So...where is the truth?

Comment: There have been at least 3 iterations of the "Ask Question" wizard. To get accurate statistics, it'll be important to specify which version you're talking about.

Comment: @CodyGray AFAIK, Sara was talking about the last one, which Julia was written about.

Comment: The truth is that they also didn't see an increase in question quality, is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're reading only half of what the article says. *Step 1* saw a decrease in quality, yes. That was mitigated by the changes of Step 2, resulting in no net difference. Thus the entire project, combining both steps, did not see any decrease in question quality.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for the company to share detailed statistics on this one?